# write base64 to file using stream

Tags: node.js, express

I am sending a base64 string to my server. On the server I want to create a readable stream that I push the base64 chunks onto that then goes to a writable stream and written to file. My problem is only the first chunk is written to file. My guess is because I create a new buffer with each chunk this is what is causing the problem but if I send just the string chunks in without creating the buffer the image file is corrupt.

```
var readable = new stream.Readable();

readable._read = function() {}

req.on('data', function(data) {
    var dataText = data.toString();
    var dataMatch = dataText.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/);
    var bufferData = null;

    if (dataMatch) {
        bufferData = new Buffer(dataMatch[2], 'base64')
    }

    else {
        bufferData = new Buffer(dataText, 'base64')
    }

    readable.push(bufferData)
})

req.on('end', function() {
    readable.push(null);
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not so trivial as you might think:

1. Use `Transform`, not `Readable`. You can `pipe` request stream to transform, thus handling back pressure.
2. You can't use regular expressions, because text you are expecting can be broken in two or more chunks. You could try to accumulate chunks and exec regular expression each time, but if the format of stream is incorrect (that is, not a  `data` uri) you will end up buffering the whole request and running regular expression a lot of times on megabytes long string.
3. You can't take arbitrary chunk and do `new Buffer(chunk, 'base64')` because it may not be valid itself. Example: `new Buffer('AQID', 'base64')` yields `new Buffer([1, 2, 3])`, but `Buffer.concat([new Buffer('AQ', 'base64'), new Buffer('ID', 'base64')])` yields `new Buffer([1, 32])`

For the 3 problem you can use one of available modules (like [base64-stream](https://www.npmjs.org/package/base64-stream)). Here is an example:

```
var base64 = require('base64-stream');
var stream = require('stream');

var decoder = base64.decode();
var input = new stream.PassThrough();
var output = new stream.PassThrough();

input.pipe(decoder).pipe(output);

output.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});

input.write('AQ');
input.write('ID');
```

You can see that it buffers input and emits `data` as soon as enough arrived.

As for the 2 problem you need to implement simple stream parser. As an idea: wait for `data:` string, then buffer chunks (if you need them) until `;base64,` found, then pipe to `base64-stream`.

Comment: Thanks @vkurchatkin! I am not sure I follow all of what you are saying. I want to push each chunk as it comes onto the stream. I have a working solution with on('data' and concating each chunk then creating a buffer and pushing onto the stream, but as I stated I want to stream each chunk. I tried base64-stream briefly before I posted this question but was not getting it to work. Can you give a quick rough code example.